# An algorithmic backtracking. Count perfect matching in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching, backtracking

So I'm a cs student, and we were asked to build a backtracking program in c (no loops only recursion) which gets an adjacency matrix of an undirected unweighed (no lifts) graph, and returns the number of perfect matching in that graph or zero otherwise.
I thought of using fkt algorithm which uses the pfaffian orientation, but so far I haven't figured out how to do so.
If you could be so very kind and maybe direct me to the right book or the right way to look at this question I'll be very grateful.
It's the first time I tried to backtrack and I think I'm missing some basic conceptions of how to implement such a thing.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?  Right now I don't know how to help since I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: So fkt algorithm as you can see here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm) uses a very nice approach but when I come up to building t2 and finish off the directed G I'm getting lost and can't produce my self a proper pseudo code of what I need to do. On paper I can handle it but that's still doesn't get me where I'm trying to get. Producing the skew-symmetric matrix and the rest of the problem I can handle but that point in the middle (lines 5 and 6 in the algorithm) are of some problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

FKT is for *planar* graphs only. If you want to implement it (and *you* almost certainly don't, since that would be a lousy homework; this is for other people who find this question), you'll need to [planarity test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing) the graph in such a way that you obtain an embedding, then implement the orientation algorithm described in [these slides](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/am994/presentations/matchings.pdf). (Sketch: find a spanning tree in the primal graph and orient those edges arbitrarily. The edges not in the spanning tree comprise a spanning tree in the dual graph. Visit the nodes of the latter tree in postorder; the parent edge of each node (= primal face) visited is the last incident edge whose orientation is undetermined, so orient it clockwise if the face currently has an even number of clockwise edges and counterclockwise otherwise.)